# gunicorn + django + telegram + mqtt client

Tags: django, gunicorn

We use gunicorn with django and [django-telegrambot](https://github.com/telebotter/django-telegrambot). We also have a MQTT client in an own app. When some MQTT messages arrive we send Telegram messages and the other way around. The Problem is now that when we use gunicorn with multiple workers, we have multiple MQTT Clients, so that when a MQTT message arrives we will send multiple times the same Telegram message.
When we use gunicorns preload with workers, we only have one MQTT client, but then all processes share the same Telegram TCP connection and we get wired SSL errors. As an alternative we could use only use on process and multiple threads, but then sometimes MQTT and Telegram messages gets not processed (idk why).
Is there a way to get this running?
Instead of using webhooks one could use botpolling, but [django-telegrambot](https://github.com/telebotter/django-telegrambot#original-features) says:

> Polling mode by management command (an easy to way to run bot in local machine, not recommended in production!)

Comment: Hi. Please remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, which is for the library with the same name ;)

Comment: The library is used internally inside of django-telegrambot. Maybe you can answer the question why polling should not be used in production? I currently see this as the only answer to my problem because than I only have one process doing mqtt and telegram.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `django-telegrambot` library, so I can't judge why the authors chose to make this statement (maybe ask on the GitHub repository …). However, both polling and webhooks are officially supported by Telegram (see [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates)). IMHO both have pros and cons. Webhooks *may* have a slight performance benefit over polling, but also require more work to set up. Polling requires you to continuously fetch for updates, which can be seen as downside. OTOH with webhooks you have to have a webserver running. For small to medium sized bots (in terms of usernumber), polling should be fine - I'm using polling without problems for my (rather small) bots.

Please take this with a grain of salt as I'm far from being an expert on networking topics.

Comment: Probably polling is fine for our bot, but we have not switched to a solution where we execute the MQTT handlers only when we run a new command. Then we still can use WebHooks but don't have the problem that the MQTT message => Telegram message handlers are executed n times.